# How to update Athena tables in a zero-down-time manner?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am deploying Athena external tables, and want to update their definition without downtime, is there a way?

The ways I thought about are:
Create a new table and rename the old and then rename the new to the old name, first, it involves a very small downtime, and renaming tables doesn't seem to be supported (neither altering the definition).
The other way is to drop the table and recreate it, which obviously involves downtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Glue UpdateTable API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-tables-UpdateTable) you can change a table definition without first dropping the table. Athena uses the Glue Catalog APIs behind the scenes when you do things like `CREATE TABLE …` and `DROP TABLE …`.

Please note that if you make changes to partitioned tables you also need to update all partitions to match.

Another way that does not involve using Glue directly would be to create a view for each table and only use these views in queries. When you need to replace a table you create a new table with the new schema, then recreate the view (with `CREATE OR REPLACE`) to use the new table, then drop the old table. I haven't checked, but it would make sense if replacing a view used the `UpdateTable` API behind the scenes.